# form request validation in laravel 6 and vue does not triggering anything

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working in laravel 6 and vueJs; I want to validate the form request using the custom laravel form request. But it does not trigger any validation error instead gives this error message (500 (Internal Server Error)).

this my code. if anyone could help me would be greatly appreciated.

signup.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-form @submit.prevent="signup" class="signup-form">
            <v-text-field
                label="Name"
                v-model="form.name"
                type="text"
                required
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-text-field
                label="E-mail"
                v-model="form.email"
                type="email"
                required
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-text-field
                label="Password"
                v-model="form.password"
                type="password"
                required
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-text-field
                label="Password_confirmation"
                v-model="form.Password_confirmation"
                type="password"
                required
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-btn type="submit" color="green">signup</v-btn>

            <router-link to="/login">
                <v-btn color="blue">Login</v-btn>
            </router-link>

        </v-form>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                form: {
                    name: null,
                    email: null,
                    password: null,
                    password_confirmation: null
                }
            }
        },
        errors: {},
        methods: {
            signup() {
                axios.post('/api/auth/signup', this.form)
                    .then(res => this.responseAfterLogin(res))
                    .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style>
    .signup-form {
        margin-top: -120px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

Auth controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\SignupRequest;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('JWT', ['except' => ['login', 'signup']]);
    }


    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Signup part added manually
     */
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name'     => 'required',
            'email'    => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',

        ]);


        User::create($request->all()); // the problem is not bcrypting the password section
        // login the registered user
        return $this->login($request);
    }


    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type'   => 'bearer',
            'expires_in'   => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'username'     => auth()->user()->name,
        ]);
    }
}
```

SignupRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SignupRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'     => 'required',
            'email'    => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the message you're getting with the 500 error?

Comment: You are not using `SignupRequest` anywhere

Comment: Just gives me POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/signup 500 (Internal Server Error) error in console when I open network there is no response data

Answer (score -1):

You must define SignupRequest class on your controller for work defined rules. Example usage for signup function,

```
     public function signup(SignupRequest $request)
     {
        User::create($request->all()); // the problem is not bcrypting the password section
        // login the registered user
        return $this->login($request);
     }
```

Also you should define $token variable on login function.
Finally, you can find error details on under storage/logs/ folder files.

I hope this help you.

Comment: ```use App\Http\Requests\SignupRequest``` They have imported the class.

Comment: I have imported the SignupRequest at the top of controller and used SignupReqest instead of simple Request but still gives me 500 internal server error

Comment: #3 [interna {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Uncaught ErrorException: Undefined variable: Exception in F:\\Learning\\Udemy\\RealTime Single Page Forum App with Pusher Laravel & vuejs\\projects\
ealtimeApp\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php:50
Stack trace:

Comment: Error about undefined variable and I think problem in login function, because $token variable didn't defined before.